Why do Mk 12:34, Lk 29:40 and Mtt 22:46 present identical Verse against different contexts?
We see three identical sounding verses in the Gospels:
Mark 12:34

"When Jesus saw that he had answered wisely, he said to him, 'You are not far from the kingdom of God.' And after that no one dared ask him any more questions".

Luke 20:40

"And no one was able to answer him a word, nor from that day did anyone dare to ask him any more questions".

Matthew 22:46

"No one could say a word in reply, and from that day on no one dared to ask him any more questions".

Interestingly, the settings of the verses are different from case to case. In Mark, it is Jesus' discourse on the Greatest Commandments; in Matthew  it is the question involving Jesus' ancestry vis-a-vis David and in Luke it is the discourse on souls' marital status in heaven.
In holistic perspective, it appears that the Verse is rather a compliment from the part of the respective Evangelist for Jesus' ability to silence his rivals in spiritual debate , than a factual statement (that no question whatsoever was thereafter posed to Jesus). Note the common-to-all use of ' dared not ask' phrase. In fact, Jesus continued to face questions,  for instance,  from Pilate who asked " What is truth ?" ( Jn 18:38).
My question is : How do Bible scholars explain the presentation of identical Verse at  Mk 12:34, Lk 29:40 and Mtt 22:46 against different contexts  ?

I think you have to trust the evangelist authors (and trust the Lord) that what is presented to us is truthful. It is certainly the case that all four authors report facts but not necessarily in the order in which they occurred or attaching dialogue to the event which (originally) precipitated them. We are given what we are given (by the Lord the Spirit) and we should respect the Divine Author's wisdom in the arrangement. Those who merely see a human author and human activity miss the relevance and miss the spirituality of the documents.

Thanks, Nigel J. I believe that it is such small differences that make the scriptures authentic, un-edited and un- biased.

"No one dared to ask" is a common enough expression that we need not presume it constitutes a specific verse placed in differt contexts. In addition, there is another instance of this expression in the Gospel of John:
John 21:12

Jesus said to them, “Come, have breakfast.” And none of the disciples
dared to ask him, “Who are you?” because they realized it was the
Lord.

Conclusion: The phrase is common. It is not a saying of Jesus which the gospel writers placed in different contexts. Rather, it is a literary phrase which all four gospel writers happened to use to describe different events.

In every time and place there are "pet phrases" (aka idioms) which are used to convey a given sentiment. We should not be surprised to find such in the biblical texts, employed in disparate passages. Sometimes these can be hyperbolic, as is the case here. For example, consider some of the hyperbolic statements that everyone ran off to do something, which is surely not suggesting 100% participation:

And the king went up to the house of the LORD, and with him all the men of Judah and all the inhabitants of Jerusalem and the priests and the prophets, all the people, both small and great. And he read in their hearing all the words of the Book of the Covenant that had been found in the house of the LORD. (2 Kgs 23:2)


Then all the men of Judah and Benjamin assembled at Jerusalem within the three days. It was the ninth month, on the twentieth day of the month. And all the people sat in the open square before the house of God, trembling because of this matter and because of the heavy rain. (Ezra 10:9)


And all the country of Judea and all Jerusalem were going out to him and were being baptized by him in the river Jordan, confessing their sins. (Mark 1:5)

This is simply a part of language.
